# mysql can't be opend or restarted

Tags: mysql

i have a probleme with mysql: since this morning when i try to open it with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

the answer is alway

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

i did allready try to use

```
mysql restart
```

or

```
service mysql restart
```

but it don't do work either and this mysql.sock file dosent exist.

Answer (score 0):

Start:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Stop:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Restart / reload configs:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Check run status:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status
```

Then try:
Stop the current MySQL server instance:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Then start MySQL:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

you may also try:
the command in terminal to use mysql interpreter:

```
mysql -u root -p database_name
```

Enter your password, then you can run your mysql commands.

Another way is to use:

```
mysql -u root -p database_name
```